# Nuxt server middleware doesn't work on Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, middleware

I'm trying to deploy a [Nuxt app](https://github.com/belgacea/nuxt-firebase-ssr) on Firebase to take advantage of SSR. This app use Nuxt [server middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware#custom-api-endpoint) as an API endpoint (to send mail).

It works fine locally, but not once deployed, nor emulated. I get a 404 response when I try to query it and I don't understand why.
Did someone already managed to create an API endpoint on Firebase using Nuxt middleware ?

NB: The repo link I shared only contains the bare minimum to reproduce the issue (not my entire app).

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
const webpack = require("webpack")
const { config } = require('dotenv')
config({ path: `../.env` })

module.exports = {
  mode: "universal",
  ...
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/pwa",
    [
      "@nuxtjs/firebase",
      {
        config: { ... },
        services: {
          analytics: true,
          performance: true,
          functions: true
        },
        onFirebaseHosting: true,
      }
    ]
  ],
  buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/axios"],
  serverMiddleware: ["./api/contact"],
  ...
}
```

`src/index.js`

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
const express = require("express")
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require("nuxt")
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors({ origin: true }))

const config = {
  dev: false,
  buildDir: ".nuxt",
  build: {
    publicPath: "/assets/"
  }
}
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

exports.nuxtapp = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  } else {
    res.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600");
    await nuxt.ready()
  }
  app.use(nuxt.render)
  return app(req, res)
})
```

`src/api/contact.js`

```js
const express = require("express")

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.status(405).json({ error: "Query invalid" });
})

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  ...
})

module.exports = {
  path: "/api/contact",
  handler: app
}
```

Debugging logs

```sh
[debug] [2021-02-05T03:22:21.137Z] [functions] Got req.url=/nuxt-firebase-ssr-41d40/us-central1/nuxtapp/api/contact/, mapping to path=/api/contact/ {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"[functions] Got req.url=/nuxt-firebase-ssr-41d40/us-central1/nuxtapp/api/contact/, mapping to path=/api/contact/"}}
[debug] [2021-02-05T03:22:21.158Z] [runtime-status] [22988] Ephemeral server handling POST request {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"nuxtapp"},"message":"[runtime-status] [22988] Ephemeral server handling POST request"}}
[info] >  » Rendering url /api/contact/ {"user":"» Rendering url /api/contact/","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"nuxtapp"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m » Rendering url /api/contact/"}}
[debug] [2021-02-05T03:22:21.160Z] [runtime-status] [22988] Ephemeral server survived. {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"nuxtapp"},"message":"[runtime-status] [22988] Ephemeral server survived."}}
[debug] [2021-02-05T03:22:21.192Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST http://localhost:5001/nuxt-firebase-ssr-41d40/us-central1/nuxtapp/api/contact/ 404
[debug] [2021-02-05T03:22:21.193Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST http://localhost:5001/nuxt-firebase-ssr-41d40/us-central1/nuxtapp/api/contact/ [stream]
[info] i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2021:03:22:21 +0000] "POST /api/contact/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36" {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hosting"},"message":"127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2021:03:22:21 +0000] \"POST /api/contact/ HTTP/1.1\" 404 - \"http://localhost:5000/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36\""}}
[info] i  functions: Finished "nuxtapp" in ~1s {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"nuxtapp"},"message":"Finished \"nuxtapp\" in ~1s"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with nuxt, but it looks like you aren't loading your config into the instance you make in `src/index.js`. I believe it should be:

```
const config = require('./nuxt.config.js')
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)
```

At the very least, your config object in `src/index.js` probably needs to have the `serverMiddleware` property defined. I'm pretty sure that `new Nuxt()` does not automatically load the `nuxt.config.js` file.